# How to auto-update a property in Realm or NSFetchedProperty equivalent?

Tags: ios, realm, swift2

I'm trying to implement one example on Realm, which using Core Data I had two options:

How to auto-update a property after a object has been inserted in the relationship? Eg. After creating a new Expense Transaction, listed under `account.transactions: List<Transaction>`, how to recalculate the `account.balance` automatically?

On Core Data I could either listen to a KVO on the transactions relationship or use a `NSFetchedProperty` that would refetch the column for me.

Is there a way to accomplish the same result on Realm, without having to listen to every database update?

Answer (score 0):

*(Disclaimer: I work for Realm)*

We recently made Realm Objects fully KVO compliant. :)

So, for your scenario, it should simply be a matter of attaching an observer to your Object's List property and updating it when you receive notifications from there.

Let me know how you go!

Comment: what do you mean by recently, is it released already? I tried to watch a property with KVO and it complains about saving an object that has a observer.

Comment: Yes, it was released in Realm 0.95 a few months back. Yes, that's correct; you cannot add a new object to a Realm file while it has observers attached. You'll need to add it and then attach it after. More info is available on the Realm site: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#key-value-observation

Comment: Yeah, I've read that, but I still don't get it. If my intention is to update the `balance` attribute and save the `account` to a Realm again, how can I observe and save simultaneously?